# Update multi-fields with Groovy Script in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I have below mapping with multi-fields :-

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "city": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"   
                        }    
                    }
                }    
            }   
        }    
    }
}
```

I am using Ingest Pipeline with Script Processor. I just want to set the value of city.raw using groovy script. I have tried various options of groovy but I am not able to access it. Below is one option which I have tried.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/pipe2
{
    "processors" : [
    {    
        "script": {
            "lang": "groovy",
            "inline": "ctx.city.raw='new City'"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can somebody help me on this

Comment: What's your expectation? I see you want to chage `city.raw` but why? What are you trying to fix?

Comment: I have below use case which i want to satisfy -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43908332/elasticsearch-groovy-script-syntax-to-set-nested-fields-value